# Number of Comparisons finding the median of 7 numbers

Tags: algorithm, compare, median, minimum

I can find the median with 12 comparisons. But I want to know the minimum number of comparisons and how to do it.

Comment: I'd like to see your implementation - I can't seem to do it in fewer than 18 operations.

Comment: For a,b,c,d,e,f,g, try a<b,c<d, then make a<b, c<d;try b<d and let the winner compare with e, then eliminate the winner. Replace the winner with new key. In the worst case, I need another 3 comparisons to eliminate another key. Do it twice, then choose the largest in the last 4 keys. Is that clear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Donald Knuth has a chapter on "Minimum-Comparison Selection" in Volume III of *The Art of Computer Programming*.

Knuth says, "no general method [of selection in the minimum number of comparisons] is evident as yet" but he gives some general methods that come close to the minimum.

Looking at Table 5.3.3–1, we can see that V₄(7) = 10 (that is, you can find the 4th largest of 7 items using at most 10 comparisons), and the algorithm ("found manually by trial and error") is given in the solution to exercise 5.3.3–10.

Comment: It seems TAoCP is necessary. @-@

Comment: @zerr, No doubt, It is always necessary

Answer (score 1):

If you allow comparisons in parallel (a modern CPU will probably do this for you), you can use a [sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) to solve the problem in six steps.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the 6 comparisons implementation? Thanks

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://www.angelfire.com/blog/ronz/Articles/999SortingNetworksReferen.html

Comment: I saw that article but I think it doecan't says that n=7 could be done with 6 comparisons.

Comment: My apologies, try this: http://jgamble.ripco.net/cgi-bin/nw.cgi?inputs=7&algorithm=batcher&output=svg  --  note that I didn't say six comparisons, I said six steps (i.e., you have to perform some comparisons in parallel in a sorting network).

Answer (score 0):

For (7s) you know you're on the right track when you spot the flying robots (Hasse Diagram).  There are two main cases to verify for 10 comps; other cases are not close to the limit.
(7s) is close to a perfect puzzle, like E's Zebra Puzzle.  Not too hard, but hard enough so only the disciplined will crack it on their first go.

Now (4s, 3), also with 7 numbers, is the equal of (7s).  Here we assume that one of the numbers repeats three times (has multiplicity 3).  I won't tell you what the answer (height of the optimal ternary dec. tree) is.  Go find it fellas!